# jQuery is not able to 'connect' with the elements on my server generated webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, webmethods

I'm trying to use jQuery functionality in Software AG webMethods IDE, which generates pages on its own .. Basically, I'm giving jQuery's functions a server-generated element ID, but jQuery is unable to read it's value, or write a value to it, or do anything with it ..

Here's the code I'm using:

```
if(jQuery.isNumeric(jQuery(CAF.model("#{activePageBean.clientIds['txtInput']}").id).val()))
{
alert("its a number");
}
else
{
alert("its not a number");
}
```

txtInput is a normal input text field, and the above code is assigned to a button ... And no matter what is put into the text field, I always get the "its not a number" alert ..

Also, if I use this code instead ..

```
alert(jQuery(CAF.model("#{activePageBean.clientIds['txtInput']}").id).val());
```

... I always get an alert saying "undefined" (without the double quotes) ..

The expression returning the text field's ID is:

```
CAF.model("#{activePageBean.clientIds['txtInput']}").id
```

.. and this is:

```
jsfwmp147312:defaultForm:txtInput
```

If I instead run this webMethods built-in function to get the value:

```
CAF.model("#{activePageBean.clientIds['txtInput']}").getValue();
```

It does return the value currently in the text field ..

So basically for some reason jQuery's functions are unable to 'connect' with the page's elements ..

How do I diagnose/resolve this ?

**EDIT:**

*More information:*

If I try the following code ...

```
var myId = "jsfwmp147312:defaultForm:txtInput";
var element = document.getElementById(myId);
alert(element.value + "");
```

.. I get the string text field's string value in the alert fine, no problems ... But if I try this ...

```
var myId = "jsfwmp147312:defaultForm:txtInput";
var val2 = jQuery(myId).val();
alert(val2);
```

... I get an alert with the message "undefined" (without the double quotes) ..

Answer (score 1):

We'll need some HTML with that. I don't really understand your selector though. You say it is "assigned to a button", so you'll need a `click`.

```
jQuery(document).on("click", "#clientIds[name=txtInput]", function(){

    v = $(this).val();
    alert(v);

});
```

Overall, client-side code and server-side code don't communicate. Server-side code spits out HTML, and client-side code handles it afterward. For both to communicatie, you need to send the data via e.g. page requests or AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is : means something in the jQuery selector so it is not looking for something else.

The string needs to look like `jsfwmp147312\:defaultForm\:txtInput`

So you will need to make it work in two steps

```
var myId = CAF.model("#{activePageBean.clientIds['txtInput']}").id.replace(/:/g,"\\:");
var val = jQuery(myId).val();

if (jQuery.isNumeric( val ) {
    alert("its a number");
} else {
    alert("its not a number");
}
```

Comment: Your code seems to be heading in the right direction, but the if condition still fails. If I do `var myId = CAF.model("#{activePageBean.clientIds['txtDateInput']}").id.replace(/:/,"\\:");` and then do `alert(myId);`, I get an alert saying `jsfwmp147312\:defaultForm:txtInput` ... Can you tell me exactly what value jQuery needs, so that I can add/subtract to the string accordingly ? ..